# Meaning of "may" in "as a scholar may learn..."

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm analyzing the following phrase:

> Or as a scholar may learn some secret language of the ancients,  his
>   friends shall say: «Look! he pretends to read this book.  But it is
>   unintelligible—it is nonsense.»  Yet he delights in the Odyssey, while
>   they read vain and vulgar things.

I'm unsure of the meaning of "may" in this phrase. Looking at the Oxford Dictionary of English online, I'm pretty sure this is not meaning [2] or [3].

Meaning [1] seems strange here. The scholar "may" learn, while his friends "shall say"? What is the value of "may" in this phrase?

Comment: You know that _may_ has the common meaning of possibility? Do scholars learn ancient languages? They may. We do not know, but the question is not about ability (can learn), only possibility (may learn). The writer is setting up a scenario, a possible story, saying 'Let us say that a scholar proceeds to study a secret language. He may and he may not, but take that as a fact for this scenario. Then friends emphatically will say about him (shall say) that he has not actually learned to read it.'

Comment: Would this fragment mean the same thing? `Or as may a scholar learn some secret language...`

Comment: That is odd English unless you are writing poetry: _as the branch is bent so grows the tree_. The saying is the same as 'As the branch _may_ be bent, so will grow the tree,' but that is not spoken English.

Comment: Tomorrow, I may wear all purple, and friends surely shall say Oh God. If I do not, friends will say Thank God.

Comment: It's the 'shall' that is the unusual usage here. 'Or a scholar may learn some secret language of the ancients, and his friends say [/mock him, saying]: «Look! he pretends to read this book. But ...'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This situation is comparable to the subjunctive mood. The word “may” is a mood-setter to create a hypothetical situation. Let's look at your example again:

> Or as a scholar may learn some secret language of the ancients, his friends shall say: «Look! he pretends to read this book. But it is unintelligible—it is nonsense.» Yet he delights in the Odyssey, while they read vain and vulgar things.

The word “may” creates the hypothetical situation (of the scholar learning the language), and also sets the reader up for a result of this situation (the friends' dialogue). “May” is simply setting up a hypothetical situation with a result of an action.

This is a special case of definition 1 of [Lexico](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/may), or 1b of [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/may).